# MVC 5 Ninject - как правильно его инициализировать

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Добрый день.
Речь идет о нюгет пакете "MVC 5 Ninject",  который не создает дополнительных классов, но при этом можно пользоваться, например, классом IKernel:

```
// GET: Clients
public ActionResult Index()
{
    /*
     Через абстракцию работаем с клиентами
     */

    IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    ninjectKernel.Bind<IClientBaseRepo>().To<ClientBaseRepo>();

    IClientBaseRepo clientsObj = ninjectKernel.Get<ClientBaseRepo>();


    var client = clientsObj.GetClientList(); //new ClientBaseRepo().GetClientList();

    return View(client);
}
```

**Собственно и вопрос**: если я хочу в каждом Действии Контроллера производить манипуляции с данными, то мне каждый раз в каждом Действии надо писать подобное:

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IClientBaseRepo>().To<ClientBaseRepo>();
```

или можно в одном определенном каком-то месте сделать инициализацию и привязки?

Я думал поместить инициализацию в **какое-нибудь единственное** место Global.asax,  но добавить его в проект у меня не получилось, такого элемента просто нету в списке.

C# MVC 5.0

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постоянно вызывать методы вроде Get или Resolve у DI-контейнеров - это едва ли не худшее применение контейнеров которое можно придумать (кстати, называется этот антипаттерн Bastard Injection). Хуже только доставать один контейнер из другого.

Все внешние зависимости должны быть либо параметрами конструктора, либо публичными свойствами. Первый способ предпочтительнее, но второй тоже допустим, особенно для точек входа в ваш код (таких как контроллер в ASP.NET MVC).

Поэтому вам надо создать в контроллере свойство типа `IClientBaseRepo` и пометить его атрибутом `[Inject]`.

---

Настраивать же Ninject нужно в одном месте, такое место называется Composition Root. Для веб-приложений Composition Root - это обработчик `Application_Start` в `Global.asax.cs`, там и создавайте StandardKernel.

А для того чтобы инъекции в контроллеры работали - используйте пакет Ninject.Web.Mvc

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Наследуемся от NinjectHttpApplication. Нужно реализовать абстрактный метод CreateKernel. Для конфигурации нужно переопределить метод OnApplicationStarted и в нем сделать все не обходимые конфигурации.

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
    }
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Registration(kernel)
        return kernel;
    }

    private void Registration(IKernel kernel)
    { 
      //регистрация зависимостей
    }
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```